# What is "trunc" in VHDL: numerical example

Tags: vhdl

What does it mean ?

```
integer(trunc(log2(maximum(coeffs))));
```

I have found it in a filte implementation [here](https://github.com/BBN-Q/VHDL-FIR-filters/blob/master/src/CoeffHelpers.vhd). It is given some description:

> -- Determine the optimum power of two scaling for filter coefficients
>
> -- to make the fixed point representation with minimum leading zeros

let say, the part `log2(maximum(coeffs)) = 4,856`  , what will VHDL give as `trunc(4,856)`?

Comment: Decimal abstract literals can't contain commas in VHDL. IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.5 Abstract literals, 15.5.2 Decimal literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a IEEE function. It appears to cut off leading and trailing zeroes unless I am misunderstanding something.

[image]

https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/guilley/ENS/20171205/TP/tp_syn/doc/IEEE_VHDL_1076.2-1996.pdf

Comment: `trunc(4,856)` = 4, isnt?

Comment: @LenaPark Is that comma a divider comma or a European decimal point? I don't think trunc does anything to integers.

Answer (score 2):

trunc(x)
... round x to the nearest integer not larger in absolute value.

cp.

floor(x)
... return the largest integral value that is not greater than x.

Comment: `trunc(4,856)` = 4, isnt?

Comment: trunc(4856) = 4856.  Don't put the comma in there, it looks like there are two arguments. If it's suppose to be a decimal point then trunc(4.856) = 4